# Extract path from root to leaf in sklearn's agglomerative clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

Given some specific leaf node of the agglomerative clustering created by `sklearn.AgglomerativeClustering`, I am trying to identify the path from the root node (all data points) to the given leaf node and for each intermediate step (internal node of the tree) the list of corresponding data points, see the example below.

[image]

In this example, I consider five data points and focus on the point 3 in such a way that I want to extract the instances considered in each step starting at the root and ending at the leaf 3, so the desired result would be [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,3,4,5],[3,4],[3]]. How could I achieve this with sklearn (or if this is not possible with a different library)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code below first find all ancestors of focus point (using `find_ancestor` function below), then finds and add all descendents (`find_descendent`) of each ancestor.

First loading and training data:

```
iris = load_iris()
N = 10
x = iris.data[:N]
model = AgglomerativeClustering(compute_full_tree=True).fit(x)
```

Here is the main code:

```
ans = []
for a in find_ancestor(3)[::-1]:
    ans.append(find_descendent(a))
print(ans)
```

Which outputs in my case:

```
[[1, 9, 8, 6, 2, 3, 5, 7, 0, 4],
 [1, 9, 8, 6, 2, 3],
 [8, 6, 2, 3],
 [6, 2, 3],
 [2, 3],
 [3]]
```

To understand code of `find_ancestor`, please remember that 2 childs of a non-leaf node with index `i` are at `model.children_[i]`

```
def find_ancestor(target):
    for ind,pair in enumerate(model.children_):
        if target in pair:
            return [target]+find_ancestor(N+ind)
    return [ind+N]
```

The recursive `find_descendent` uses `mem` to keep it's output in memory so they don't get needlessly re-computed.

```
mem = {}
def find_descendent(node):
    global mem
    if node in mem: return mem[node]
    if node<N: return [node]
    pair = model.children_[node-N]
    mem[node] = find_descendent(pair[0])+find_descendent(pair[1])
    return mem[node]
```